# link 2 different types of highcharts data

Tags: highcharts

is it possible to link/sync 2 chart data in 2 different type of charts to show tooltips at once?

for an example, i have a pie chart and a area chart.

The pie chart represents the percentage of a particular browser and the area chart shows the downloads per year for each browser.

What i need to do is if someone clicks or hovers on section of the pie the relevant line and the tooltip of the area chart should be highlighted...

so when someone clicks/hovers on firefox on the pie, the line relevant to the area should show and vice versa...

is this something possible with highcharts?

So far the work i have done is https://jsfiddle.net/livewirerules/a9tntdam/1/

One thing that i noticed is i have added the `event` in my area chart to show the color when the tooltip is hovered.

```
events: {
               tooltipRefresh: function(e) {
                 if (!e.target.hoverSeries) return;
                 $('.highcharts-tooltip>path:last-of-type')
                   .css('fill', e.target.hoverSeries.color);
               }
             }
```

when i hover a line on the area chart and move to the pie chart, the background color of the tooltips are changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what would you like to show in a tooltip when you hover on your pie. You have one point so its hard to show tooltip for whole series on another chart.

You can use mouseOver and mouseOut events callback functions for highlighting series (so they will look like on hover):

```
point: {
  events: {
    mouseOver: function() {
      var name = this.name;
      Highcharts.each(chart2.series, function(s) {
        if (name === s.name) {
          s.setState('hover');
        }
      });
    },
    mouseOut: function() {
      var name = this.name;
      Highcharts.each(chart2.series, function(s) {
        if (name === s.name) {
          s.setState('');
        }
      });
    }
  }
},
```

You can use tooltip.refresh(point) for refreshing tooltip on specific point:

```
      mouseOver: function(e) {
        this.group.toFront();
        this.markerGroup.toFront();
        var name = this.name;
        Highcharts.each(chart.series[0].data, function(p) {
          if (name === p.name) {
            p.setState('hover');
            chart.tooltip.refresh(p)
          }
        });
      },
```

Here you can see an example how it can work:
http://jsfiddle.net/a9tntdam/4/

Comment: awesome... thanks alot.. i have been pulling my head for weeks trying to figure this out... just one small issue... If you see in my pie chart initially when its loaded the tooltip background color site (i have set it to show the relevant color through) but when i click or hover on the line chart and come back to the pie it shows the hovered/clicked line color. for an example if u click on the blue line and come back to the to pie.. all the tooltips are blue. How can i fix that? Thanks alot again

Comment: You can use .css in you mouseOut event just like in the tooltip refresh event: http://jsfiddle.net/a9tntdam/6/